# Can't print Spring MVC model from database

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I'm making a webapp and one of the pages needs to display a date on which the user picks in the registration page. Right now, the date does not print at all.

Here is how I'm trying to print the value.

```
<c:out value="${showDate}"></c:out>
```

Here is the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/done", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView done(User user) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    String showDate = user.getInstallationDate();
    model.addObject("showDate", showDate);
    model.setViewName("done");
    return model;
}
```

Here is how installationDate() is made

```
@Column(name = "installation_date")
private String installationDate;

public String getInstallationDate() {
    return installationDate;
}

public void setInstallationDate(String installationDate) {
    this.installationDate = installationDate;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? If more code or explanation is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. I am not totally sure why this works so if someone wants to elaborate in the comments so others can see, feel free.

Here is my code now.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/done**", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView done(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();

    String installationDate = user.getInstallationDate();
    model.addObject("installationDate", installationDate);
    model.setViewName("done");
    return model;
}
```

and I print it like this

```
${user.installationDate}
```

And I added this in my jsp

```
<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="user" commandName="user">
```

I added the form tag after the body tag and the ending tag next to the ending tag of body.

I did not change the getters and setters